# How to configure Single-Server Private Network in Xenserver without using VLAN?

Tags: networking, xenserver

I would like to create a Single Server private Network on a Xenserver which will be used for communication between the host and the VMs.  I am able to achive this by creating a vlan and configuring the pif.

But when looking at the XenCenter, there is an explicit option to create such a network without the VLAN stuff.  Where would I configure it using xe or Xencenter commands?  I can see it in network-list, ifconfig and brctl, but where would I set the local IPs?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe the only possible way to accomplish that is what you did. Single Server Private Networks are designed to communication amongst virtual machines only, and not to the host itself.

Answer (score -1):

There is way how to configure it via XenCenter Management console.

> In networking > Add network > Single-Server Private Network

Comment: Thank you, that is the way to create it in Xencenter.  But it does not provide any configuration options.  The point of my question is, if there is a Xenserver/Xencenter way of configuring (eg. set an IP for the Xen host) the Single-Server network.  I am currently only able to do this, if I set up the network as an external network/VLAN instead of the Single-Server option.

Comment: A Single-Server Private Network cannot be used to communication between virtual machines and the host itself, only amongst virtual machines.